# Okta Javascript Auth API fails on Android

Tags: javascript, android, single-sign-on, okta, okta-api

I'm implementing SSO for my product using Okta Authentication Javascript API. The code is something like this (I use Aurelia as front-end framework):

```
  login() {
    var OktaAuth = require('@okta/okta-auth-js');
    this.authClient = new OktaAuth({url: 'https://myurl.okta.com'});
    var $this = this;
    $this.authClient.signIn({
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password
      })
      .then(function(transaction) {
        if (transaction.status === 'SUCCESS') {
          $this.authClient.session.setCookieAndRedirect(transaction.sessionToken, 'https://myredirecturl.com'); 
        } else {
          alert(transaction.status);
          console.error('Error status: ' + transaction.status);
        }
      })
      .fail(function(err) {
        alert(err + ' ' + err.errorSummary + ' ' + err.errorCode);
        console.error(err);
      });
  }
```

It works perfectly on my desktop with Windows 7, but when I test the same application on my Android mobile device I get AuthApiError with errorSummary and errorCode undefined. Do you know if there are any issues with Okta Auth working on Android (other mobile devices) and what can be done here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was an issue with CORS. I used a special url to connect to my app via mobile - when I added it to trusted domains in Okta admin dashboard the isseu was resolved.